# I need help with those sentences: 「～と思われる」「～ように思われる」

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> 日本語を習う時はローマ字を使わない方が良いと思われる。
>   日本の将来の見込みは暗いように思われる。
>   彼は金持ちであるように思われる。

Why does the first one use と and the second and third one use ように?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ように思う what is the exact meaning?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61489/%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab%e6%80%9d%e3%81%86-what-is-the-exact-meaning)

Answer (score 3):

IMO:

1. と思われる indicates a slightly higher confidence compared to ように思われる
2. ように思われる indicates it's your perception

(2) probably needs some explanation. If you say 恥ずかしがっていると思われる then you are implicitly asserting that the state 恥ずかしがっている exists. This could be offensive, but if you say  恥ずかしがっているように思われる then it emphasizes that "it only looks like that to you", and can therefore be a softer statement. E.g. "昇進を逃して悔しがっていると思われる" could be more offensive than "昇進を逃して悔しがっているように思われる" because in the latter you are emphasizing that it merely looks like that to you.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of these sentences is:

1) When learning Japanese it is thought to be good to avoid using romaji. (the meaning is that it helps not using romaji, making an effort to use kanji or Katakana instead);
2) The future of Japan is thought to be dark.
3) He is thought to be rich./It seems like he is thought to be rich

In the first one と is more direct, while using ように思われる is a softer way to express an opinion (it seems like). I don't think it reflects much in the English translation.